# GraphHopper - Using truck profile

Tags: openstreetmap, traveling-salesman, graphhopper

I use the "Routing Web Server" application from graphHopper.
In the "config-example-properties" file I can only use a car as vehicletype. But I need a profile for trucks.

In the demos I can see, that they use also trucks.
How I have to change the config-files, that I can activate a truck profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you refer to the [bus and truck profiles here](https://github.com/graphhopper/directions-api/blob/master/supported-vehicle-profiles.md) then you have to build them on your own or buy the commercial offering which is an add-on to the open source routing engine.

BTW: In the near future building custom profiles will be a lot easier.
Note: I'm the author.

Comment: I have another question..i want to use an europe map...the map has about 16GB (europe-latest.osm.pbf)...when I start it using this map...i get everytime an Exception ("pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded)

Can you help me solve this

Comment: Try to allocate more memory to your JVM. What are your actual configuration?

Comment: @Karussell so basically graphhopper comes open-source with a car-profile but others (f.e. pedestrians) and a paid add-on? I can't find any information about those on your website. Can you point me to it?

Comment: There are many open source, just a few truck profiles are not but you can create them https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/tree/master/core/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/routing/util